# Colocar Laravel em Nível/Diretório Padrão

Tags: php, laravel, apache, htaccess

Tenho uma aplicação **Laravel** e faço o **deploy** dela via git para meu servidor. Mas o problema é que o servidor sempre joga o deploy **dentro da pasta public**, e o Laravel originalmente **é pra ficar um nível acima**.

Aí toda vez depois de fazer o deploy, eu tenho de ir lá **arrastar pastas de um lado para o outro**... Gostaria de saber se existem alternativas a isso... Uma solução usando `.htaccess` ou o próprio Laravel por exemplo...

Comment: Mas esta pasta `public` para a qual o Laravel vai dentro é a do seu servidor ou a do próprio Lavarel ?

Comment: Se tiver acesso altere o script de deploy e aponte para acima. Ou é Servidor compartilhado?

Comment: Compartilhado... :/

Comment: Do servidor, DeeSouza... Ao acessar meu site, www.site.com a pasta que é acessada é a pasta 'public' do servidor, mas o Laravel tem sua própria pasta 'public'... Aí no eu teria que acessar meu site assim: www.site.com/public pra dar certo ou jogar meu Laravel manualmente 1 nível acima...

Comment: +1 pela pergunta. Dê uma olhada para ver se os três métodos te ajudará

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma maneira de resolver isso pelo `.htaccess` e pelo `laravel`. E uma gambiarra extra que vou te ensinar (talvez seja o jeito mais fácil).

## HTACCESS

A do `htaccess` consiste em escrever o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

## LARAVEL

Você terá que mover o arquivo `public/index.php`para a raiz, ou seja apenas `./index.php`.

Exemplo:

```
 //index.php (agora fora da pasta public)

 //require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/start.php'

 require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap/start.php'
```

Depois disso, terá que altera a forma que os arquivos `index.php` e `bootstrap/paths.php` estão sendo utilizados pela função `require` (vai ter que tirar a string `/../` que fica no início).

## Gambiarra Extra (Powered By Wallace)

Você pode simplesmente criar um arquivo `index.php` na raiz e incluir o arquivo que está dentro de `public/index.php`.

Da seguinte forma:

```
//index.php

require __DIR__ .  '/public/index.php';
```

Dos três métodos, recomendaria o `htaccess`.

Comment: Ja usei essa gambiarra ai